# How to implement user notifications

Tags: android, notifications, android-actionbar, parse-platform

I'm trying to set up a UI similar to facebook/twitter/google+  with notifications to connected users :

[image: Facebook's actionbar]

note that my users are connected with facebook, then a parse.com user is created with facebook's informations.

Can you give me a link to a guide or tutorial about setting up this notification system for logged in users ? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a table for user notifications i.e. Notifications

so you just need to add "unread" column and do as the following

1. when the Adding any notification to this table set unread to
   True
2. when the user login count the records in Notifications which belong
   to this user and has unread = True
3. if the user viewed the notifications update unread to false